# Z-index и клик по нижнему объекту

Tags: iframe, css

Суть в чем: есть видео ютуб, и есть картинка телевизора, которая его замещает, то есть чтобы как будто видео в телевизоре.

Код:

```
<div style="position: relative; z-index:5; width: 100%; text-align:center; top: -450px;">
<img  src="/images/front-l.png" alt="" style="position: absolute; z-index:5; width: 600px; height: 399px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" />

<iframe  style="position: absolute; z-index:4; width: 562px; height: 321px; top: 18px; left: 18px;"  src="//www.youtube.com/embed/foGBFooM6eU?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>
```

Вопрос в слейдуйщем: не могу кликнуть по плеере, чтобы запустить видео. Как решить? Видел такое на многих сайтах, но сейчас найти не могу (((

Вот пациент: http://d.monitor-obmen.ru/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поставьте для картинки вот такое css свойство:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Таким образом, все клики будут идти сквозь нее.

Comment: Спасибо, то, что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

Для **iframe** увеличьте **z-index** - от **5** и выше,
тогда будет работать:

```
<div style="position: relative; z-index:5; width: 100%; text-align:center; top: -450px;">
<img  src="/images/front-l.png" alt="" style="position: absolute; z-index:5; width: 600px; height: 399px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" />

<iframe  style="position: absolute; z-index:5; width: 562px; height: 321px; top: 18px; left: 18px;"  src="//www.youtube.com/embed/foGBFooM6eU?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>
```

Comment: в таком случае плеер будет размещен поверх изображения, а мне какраз нужно чтобі изображение закрівало некоторые участки плеера, но чтобы пллер работал.